# How can clients authenticate to a proxy without user intervention?

Tags: proxy, authentication

I would like to set up a number of computers that need to go through a proxy server to get to the outside world.  The OS is Ubuntu 12.04 but the issue seems common to all versions (are far as I can tell).

Every post I read says to put `user:password@proxy:port` in the `apt.conf` file, and yes that works, but it's not really a option.  The computers are being used by non technical people with a 3 month password change policy.

Asking them to store their password in plain text, or encrypt their password and put it in a text file is just not going to happen.

I can get the computers authenticating to an AD domain and Firefox will happily pass the credentials along, but I can't get the Update or Software Centre to do the same thing.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for a proxy solution for web browsing or for package management? It not clear to me from your question.

Answer (score 1):

Change your point of view.
Don't configure the authentication task on the clients, do it on the server side.

The approach is either to set up an restricted web proxy with either no or an "static" password. This web proxy should use a white-listing that allow access to well-known package repositories, but inhibits the use of custom web sites. This way the approach should not interfere with the web access policies for the users in your organization.

As an alternative to a traditional web proxy like `squid` you may have also a look at something like `apt-cacher`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I initially asked the Admin guys to open up ports for the updates but they tried and then put it in the 'too hard' basket.  I figured there should be a client side solution.  I am surprised that there doesn't seem to be since the need seems obvious (at least to me) and that Firefox does it quite happily.